# Cassandra - Get on CF with key returning 0 results, but key exists when retrieving whole table using pycassa

Tags: nosql, cassandra, pycassa

We have a table in Cassandra 1.2.0. That has an VarInt key. When we search keys we can see that they exist.

Table description:

```
CREATE TABLE u (
key varint PRIMARY KEY,
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
comment='' AND
dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
read_repair_chance=1.000000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

Select key from u limit 10;
```

*key*

12040911

60619595

3220132

4602232

3997404

6312372

1128185

1507755

1778092

4701841

When I try and get the row for key 60619595 it works fine.

cqlsh:users> select key from u where key = 60619595;

*key*

60619595

```
cqlsh:users> select key from u where key = 3997404;
```

When I use pycassa to get the whole table I can access the row.

```
import pycassa
from struct import *
from pycassa.types import *
from urlparse import urlparse
import operator

userspool = pycassa.ConnectionPool('users');
userscf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(userspool, 'u');
users = {}
u = list(userscf.get_range())
for r in u:
users[r[0]] = r[1]
print users[3997404]
```

returns the correct result.

What am I doing wrong? I cannot see what the error is.

Any help would be appreciated,

Regards

Michael.

PS:
I should say that in pycassa when I try:

```
userscf.get(3997404)
```

File "test.py", line 10, in 
userscf.get(3997404)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycassa/columnfamily.py", line 655, in get
raise NotFoundException()
pycassa.cassandra.ttypes.NotFoundException: NotFoundException(_message=None)

It seems to be in Ints that are smaller than the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing CQL and Thrift-based queries, which do not always mix well.  CQL abstracts the underlying storage rows, whereas Thrift deals directly with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem we are having in our project. I should have added that

select key from u where key = 3997404;
cqlsh:users>

returns 0 results, even although when select * from u in cqlsh, or get the whole table in pycassa we see the row with the key 3997404.

Sorry for the confusion.

Regards

D.